# Go 1.7 Cross Compilation from Windows to Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: go, cross-platform

I have GO 1.7 installed on my Windows 10. I created test program and it works perfectly in Windows. Next step is to try to run it on my docker virtual machine with Ubuntu.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829155/how-to-cross-compile-from-windows-to-linux) some info about the way to do it

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOOS=linux
go tool dist install -v pkg/runtime
go install -v -a std
```

I run line 1 and 2 in cmd and there is no problem. At line 3 I have an error

```
go tool dist: open C:\Go\src\pkg\runtime: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I check manually this folder and there is a runtime only for windows

[image]

The question is where and how can I download it for linux? Or maybe thats I'm doing is completely wrong way...

**UPDATE 09/02/2017**

I ran like it was suggested

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOOS=linux
go build -o "myapp"
```

After I copied this file to shared folder, copied form there to another not shared folder (to avoid an issue described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648555/bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error/697757#697757)) and executed

```
root@7dd1655ae5db:/__notshared# ./myapp
bash: ./myapp: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

After I downloaded file package checked my file

```
root@7dd1655ae5db:/__notshared# file myapp
myapp: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
```

It seems that during build not linux executable was created.

Comment: I think you don't need the third command, just installing the std (ie `go install std`) is enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a problem and a solution of it.

In my Windows 10 these commands

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOOS=linux
```

in cmd and also in powershell console did really nothing! Only the way it works is that I need to open Control Panel -> System -> System Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables and add them there manually.

[image]

If you use Visual Studio Code for development, do not forget to restart it.

**UPDATE 24/02/2017**

Instead all above you can set variable in windows powershell like this

> $env:GOOS = "linux"

and read it to console

> $env:GOOS

Comment: _"The `SET` command did realy nothing!"_ The `SET` command does not set the environment variable system-wide, only in the current command shell. So to other shells and apps it has no effect, this is no secret.

Comment: But this even did not for current command shell. I set it, make build, copy my file to my linux container, run "file" comand and see that file is build for windows. Only when I do it to whole system the way I described, it works. I do not know why but it's like this for my windows 10

Comment: Just for vscode, you can do:

  File->Preference->Settings: search for go.toolsEnvVars
  => add inside:
      `"GOARCH": "amd64",
      "GOOS": "linux"`

There is no need to restart

Answer (score 9):

That other question is a bit old (from 2013).

Cross-platform support evolved a lot, all you need to do is change the environment variables (`GOARCH` and `GOOS`) and run `go build`.

Navigate to the folder of the `main` package, then:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOOS=linux
go build
```

You may change the name of the result binary like this:

```
go build -o "myapp"
```

Note that in Linux to compile the app for Windows amd64, a single command is enough (in the folder of the `main` package):

```
GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

This is also confirmed in blog post: [Dave Cheney: Cross compilation with Go 1.5](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5):

> To cross compile a Go program using Go 1.5 the process is as follows:
>
> 1. set `GOOS` and `GOARCH` to be the values for the target [operating system and architecture](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment).
> 2. run `go build -v YOURPACKAGE`

#### Notes

You don't have to, and you shouldn't run `go install`, as that will compile and install the packages in your `GOPATH`, which is often not wanted. Doing cross compilation is not for developing / testing your app and packages. It is to produce a single binary which you will run on another system / computer.

`go build` will not install anything, it will just produce the executable binary. For details, see [What does go build build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build)

Also confirmed in blog post: [Dave Cheney: Cross compilation with Go 1.5](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5):

> When cross compiling, you should use `go build`, not `go install`. This is the one of the few cases where `go build` is preferable to `go install`.
>
> The reason for this is `go install` always caches compiled packages, `.a` files, into the `pkg/` directory that matches the root of the source code.

Comment: I believe that when cross-compiling you still have to have the standard lib for the target platform installed. I use ie `sudo env GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 /usr/local/go/bin/go install std` to enable cross-compiling for win64 on my Ubuntu.

Comment: @ain No, it doesn't. In Linux, all you need to do is run `GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build` in the folder of the main package (just verified it).

Comment: Could it be that you have already the std installed? I sure had to use the command in my first comment in order to be able to cross compile after I last time upgraded go (to 1.7). Of couse, once you have it installed you can just build from then on...

Comment: @ain No, just the "bare" binary Go distribution, from the official [Downloads](https://golang.org/dl/) page. The go tool will recompile everything needed from the standard lib (from source) to the target os/arch, that's why it takes longer.

Comment: @ain To add, you can always run `go tool dist list` to list the OS/ARCH combinations that your install of Go supports.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, on Windows 10 with Go 1.14, is the following:

```
go env -w GOARCH=amd64
go env -w GOOS=linux
go build -o test-linux test.go
```

That's it.

I tried this in both Windows command prompt and Windows PowerShell. There's no difference in results.

If you open the binary file in a text editor, you should see that it begins with ELF (Linux), and not MZ (Windows).

I ran it on a Linux machine (RHEL 7.3) with the given architecture, and it worked properly. It gave correct output.

After copying the file to the Linux machine, I had to make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x test-linux
```

Then I was able to run it:

```
$ ./test-linux
```

You can also run the following command on Linux, to get more detail about the file:

```
$ file test-linux
test-linux: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

Of course, if your architecture is `amd64` already, then you don't have to set it again. You can just set the `GOOS`.

You can also revert `GOOS` to `windows` after you're done with cross-compiling. When I closed the Windows command prompt and PowerShell, and ran `go env` to see the list of Go environment variables, and `GOOS` kept  the `linux` value. I didn't try with restarting  Windows. So, if you now want to compile for Windows again:

```
go env -w GOOS=windows
```

You need to use the correct casing, as shown here. For example, `Windows` or `Linux` won't work.