# How to CrossCompile Go programs on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, go, cross-compiling

I want to compile a Go programm for a linux machine. I always used that way which is described here:

[How to cross compile from Windows to Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829155/how-to-cross-compile-from-windows-to-linux#20830892)

That worked pretty well until the last big update from Windows 10. Now I am not able to set the `GOOS` with

```
set GOOS=linux
```

I also tried to start the PowerShell as administrator, but even that is not working.
Are there any tools which can do that? Or is there another way to crosscompile Go program on Windows 10?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to set `GOOS`"? You get an error? `GOOS` not changing? Or?

Comment: The cmd does not change anything

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`set` is an internal command of the Windows command line interpreter (`cmd.exe`).

If you're using PowerShell, then changing values of environment variables should be done like:

```
$Env:<variable-name> = "<new-value>"
```

For more details, see [PowerShell documentation: About Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-6)

So to change `GOOS`, use:

```
$Env:GOOS = "linux"
```

To do a cross-compilation:

1. Navigate to the folder where the `main` package is.
2. Run `$Env:GOOS = "linux"`
3. Optionally run `$Env:GOARCH = "amd64"`
4. Run `go build`

Or you can do it in a single line:

```
$Env:GOOS = "linux"; $Env:GOARCH = "amd64"; go build
```

To specify the output file name:

```
$Env:GOOS = "linux"; $Env:GOARCH = "amd64"; go build -o hello
```