# I Can not use Cross Compiler

Tags: go, cross-compiling

I want to compile my Go code in windows 10 for Linux (Ubuntu).

I use the commands:

```
SET GOOS=linux
SET GOARCH=amd64
go build .\main.go
```

but the compiler creates an .exe file.

How to cross-compile this code for linux?

Comment: What does Linux say the file is? Are you sending the correct file? I don’t think the compiler adds a `.exe` extension when cross compiling.

Comment: Do you use PowerShell?

Comment: @VitalyMigunov Yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to CrossCompile Go programs on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911153/how-to-crosscompile-go-programs-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use PowerShell then you should use `$Env:GOOS = "linux"; $Env:GOARCH = "amd64"; go build .\main.go`

Comment: Thank very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this like a one line command in the terminal: `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build .\main.go`

Comment: I did it but made a mistake,GOOS=linux : The term 'GOOS=linux' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build .\main.go
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (GOOS=linux:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException