# cannot use int(fd) (value of type int) as syscall.Handle value in argument to syscall.SetsockoptInt

Tags: go, compiler-errors

#### I'm making a script in golang and in this part of the code I get an error in this line:

*syscall.SetsockoptInt(int(fd), syscall.IPPROTO_TCP, syscall.TCP_NODELAY, 1)*

Specifically:

**int**(fd)

```
var globalTr = &http.Transport{
    MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 4096,
    MaxIdleConns:        4096,
    MaxConnsPerHost:     4096,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout: 0 * time.Second,
    TLSClientConfig:     &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
        Control: func(network, address string, c syscall.RawConn) error {
            return c.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
                syscall.SetsockoptInt(int(fd), syscall.IPPROTO_TCP, syscall.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
            })
        },
    }).DialContext,
}
```

#### The error is:

`cannot use int(fd) (value of type int) as syscall.Handle value in argument to syscall.SetsockoptInt`

Comment: The `syscall` package is very platform specific, so you should almost always use it only within files having the correct build constraints. The code looks like it is for unix, while the error is from windows.

Comment: Note that if your only goal is to set `TCP_NODELAY `, the platform-specific work has already been done for you in [`TCPConn.SetNoDelay`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#TCPConn.SetNoDelay)

Comment: @JimB I just compiled it in a unix environment and it works perfectly, I'll settle for that. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your platform syscall's might be prototyped differently.

In this case for [Windows](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/syscall/syscall_windows.go) the prototype is:

```
func SetsockoptInt(fd Handle, level, opt int, value int) (err error)
```

While the prototype in [Unix](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/syscall/syscall_unix.go;l=309;bpv=1;bpt=1) is:

```
func SetsockoptInt(fd, level, opt int, value int) (err error) {
```

It appears you are trying to use a Window's prototype on a Unix system, which is giving you a type error because `Handle` is considered a different type from `int`.

As noted in the comments syscall functions are specific to the system specified.

See this question for more info on [cross-compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829155/how-to-cross-compile-from-windows-to-linux)  If you aren't cross-compiling you'll need to make sure your environment correctly specifies your target env.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure, in your editor/ development environment, that the environment variable GOOS is set correctly.

For example, in VSCode, search settings for `go.toolsEnvVars`. Mine was set to `windows` from a previous config for a different build target, and that produced the mismatched syscall api.